# How to webview fit to screen with getting proper x,y coordinate in Android?

Tags: android, webview, highlight, coordinate

I am implementing `HightLight` feature in my Epub reader Android Application and i want to display fit to screen `HTML` page in my `webview`  when I am not using `setUseWideViewPort(true)` and `setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);`then my text `HightLight` feature working properly because its getting proper `x,y co-ordinate`

But when i am using `setUseWideViewPort(true)` and `setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);` I am not able get proper selected text for `HighLight` and instead of it i am getting different selected text.

So what i can set for fit to screen with proper `HighLight` feature in Android

Thanks,
Girish

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can solve your problem by setting web view scroll. like:

```
webView.scrollTo(int X, int Y);
```